# Graph API requests failing / facebook dns?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The facebook graph api (graph.api.com) resolves to 173.252.101.18 almost every time. However, in some cases the DNS result ends up in 69.171.228.44. The latter host does not respont, is not ping-able and thus, sometimes API requests fail.

A friend (which is a facebook app developer as well) confirmed this behavior with his server. Another friend's DNS simply did not resolve to 69.171.228.44, so he had no problems.

What could i do? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to intercept the cases where it fails and retry resolving or just use a static preprogrammed IP (if you notice failure). It's just a stop-gap method but it seems to me the problem lies with facebook's (DNS) servers so a full fix of the problem at your side is difficult

Comment: yes, indeed. i modified the /etc/hosts to resolve graph.facebook.com and api.facebook.com to one ip address that works.
hopefully they won't change their set of adresses until they fix the error. :) :) :)